# Calculate the sum of a column by column Date in php

Tags: php

How to calculate the sum of a column by a date column?
I have `id` column and `call_time` column. I want to get the sum of `id` column based on `call_time`.

This is my sample table

[image: My table in database]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Have you attempted anything? It is just unreasonable that you want to get the sum of an ID row...

Comment: Select Sum(id) FROM table_name GROUP BY call_time

Comment: @coder Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` function on required column with `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM your_table GROUP BY call_time
```